# How to override an inline style in Html

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So we got this default "a" global inline style in wordpress, istheir any way I can change it from black to white for a particular section only just by using extrnal css?
I already tried using this but it won't work

```
#text-1714962803 a {
    color:  #FFFFFF !important;
}

<div id="text-1714962803" class="text">
        
<h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: ivyora-light; font-size: 100%; color: #000000;">LULLY &amp; ROSE Florist, nestled in the heart of the Gold Coast, a perfumed haven of <a href="https://lullyandrose.com.au/shop-3/fresh-flowers-flower-delivery-gold-coast/" data-wpel-link="internal">premium flowers</a>, <a href="https://lullyandrose.com.au/shop-3/plants-indoor-plant-delivery-gold-coast/" data-wpel-link="internal">indoor plants</a> &amp; thoughtfully curated Australian <a style="color: #000000;" href="https://lullyandrose.com.au/shop-3/gift-hampers-gift-hamper-delivery-gold-coast/" data-wpel-link="internal">gift hampers</a>.</span></h2>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">   </span></p><div id="gap-1211602490" class="gap-element clearfix" style="display:block; height:auto;">
        
   
        </div>
        <p></p>
    <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #000000;"><span style="font-size: 110%; font-family: europa-light;">With over 11 years of industry experience, we works closely with <a style="color: #000000;" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Queensland/" data-wpel-link="external" target="_blank" rel="external noopener noreferrer">Queensland flower wholesalers</a> and <a style="color: #000000;" href="https://www.septemberpeony.com" data-wpel-link="external" target="_blank" rel="external noopener noreferrer">micro growers</a> throughout the <a style="color: #000000;" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Gold+Coast+QLD/" data-wpel-link="external" target="_blank" rel="external noopener noreferrer">Gold Coast</a> Hinterland and the Northern NSW region, to source the freshest and highest quality, where every flower is personally hand-selected by us, and lovingly designed by owner and lead floral designer, Rachael. We offer same day Gold Coast flower delivery, delivered by our specialised couriers to ensure your flowers are handled with love and delivered with care.</span><span style="font-size: 120%;"><span style="font-size: 110%; font-family: europa-light;">&nbsp;</span><br>
    </span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: #000000;">   </span></p><div id="gap-1116439380" class="gap-element clearfix" style="display:block; height:auto;">
            
    <style>
    #gap-1116439380 {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
        </div>
        <p></p>
    <p><span style="font-size: 120%; color: #000000;"><a href="https://lullyandrose.com.au/our-story-gold-coast-florist/" class="button white is-outline" style="border-radius:99px;" data-wpel-link="internal">
        <span>FIND OUT MORE</span>
      </a>
    
    </span><br>
    <span style="color: #000000;"><br>
```

Comment: I guess `#text-1714962803 a:link {color:  #FFFFFF !important;}`. 

Comment: you can change certain elements a tag by declaring class in that tag eg `<p class:"para"><a href:"example.com></p>` and then applying style in css using `.para a { color:white;}`

Comment: There is a problem with your `#text-1714962803 a` selector. If you use the `a` tag with the `href` attribute, you need to select that `a` element with the `:link` pseudo-class selector. You will need to update your current selector as the `#text-1714962803 a:link` and apply your current styles to it.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction between CSS and inline styles can be summarised as follows:

- Inline styles override CSS styles.
- CSS `!important` styles override inline styles.
- Inline `!important` styles override CSS `!important` styles.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.a3, .a4 {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="a1" href="">One</a>
<a class="a2" href="" style="color: green;">Two</a>
<a class="a3" href="" style="color: green;">Three</a>
<a class="a4" href="" style="color: green !important;">Four</a>
```